# Argocd ApplicationSet, Git Generator error during fetching repo

Tags: deployment, fetch, devops, argocd, go-git

Tested a official test code in a Argo CD reference.

> https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/applicationset/Generators-Git/

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ApplicationSet
metadata:
  name: cluster-addons
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  generators:
  - git:
      repoURL: https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd.git
      revision: HEAD
      directories:
      - path: applicationset/examples/git-generator-directory/cluster-addons/*
  template:
    metadata:
      name: '{{path.basename}}'
    spec:
      project: "my-project"
      source:
        repoURL: https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd.git
        targetRevision: HEAD
        path: '{{path}}'
      destination:
        server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
        namespace: '{{path.basename}}'
      syncPolicy:
        syncOptions:
        - CreateNamespace=true
```

And when I applied an ApplicationSet to my cluster and it deploy to local cluster.
The error is like below.

```
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2022-12-23T00:53:42Z
    Message:               Error during fetching repo: `git fetch origin HEAD --tags --force --prune` failed exit status 128: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd.git/': getaddrinfo() thread failed to start
    Reason:                ApplicationGenerationFromParamsError
    Status:                True
    Type:                  ErrorOccurred
    Last Transition Time:  2022-12-23T00:53:42Z
    Message:               Error during fetching repo: `git fetch origin HEAD --tags --force --prune` failed exit status 128: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd.git/': getaddrinfo() thread failed to start
    Reason:                ErrorOccurred
    Status:                False
    Type:                  ParametersGenerated
    Last Transition Time:  2022-12-23T00:53:42Z
    Message:               Error during fetching repo: `git fetch origin HEAD --tags --force --prune` failed exit status 128: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd.git/': getaddrinfo() thread failed to start
    Reason:                ApplicationGenerationFromParamsError
    Status:                False
    Type:                  ResourcesUpToDate
Events:                    <none>
```

Is there any idea who know about it?

Comment: This isn't Git: this is some internal Go issue.

Comment: I checked it inside a "argocd-application-controller" container. 
There is same error when 'git clone https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd.git'.
- getaddrinfo() thread failed to start -

Comment: Hm, might be something else, but in any case it's not base Git, which doesn't spin up its own threads just to run the name lookups.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a bug and it can be solved with a downgrading ArgoCD version.

My version was v2.5.5 and it is a bug. ArgoCD v2.2.11 works well.

> https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/11818.